# NodeMCU external callback function generates error

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I am using NodeMCU 0.9.6 with an Adafruit HUZZAH ESP8266.

The following code, which defines the callback function within the `http.get` statement, works:

```
    http.get("http://192.168.2.38/ICmd.py?i=esp8266001", nil, function(code, data)
    if (code < 0) then
      print("***ICmd HTTP request failed")
    else
      print("***ICmd callback: ", code, data)
    end
  end)
```

The following code moves the callback function definition from within the `http.get` statement to be a standalone function:

```
function chkICmdResp(code, data)
    if (code < 0) then
      print("***ICmd HTTP request failed")
    else
      print("***ICmd callback: ", code, data)
    end
end

http.get("http://192.168.2.38/ICmd.py?i=esp8266001", nil, chkICmdResp(code, data) )
```

The second format does not work, it generates the error:

```
stdin:2: attempt to compare nil with number
stack traceback:
    stdin:2: in function 'chkICmdResponse'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
```

Am I doing something incorrectly (NodeMCU noobie)?  Or is this a design feature or a bug?

It would be nice to be able to have a single callback function that can be referenced from multiple http.get calls.

Note: I have also tried this with the `net.socket:on("receive",...)` module and got the same error result when trying to use a function that is defined outside of the calling statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a fundamental mismatch between what you're trying to do and what your firmware offers. Do NOT use those old 0.9.x NodeMCU binaries. They're based on old Espressif SDKs, they're no longer maintained and they're full of bugs.

The HTTP client module has only been around for a few months. It's currently only available in the NodeMCU `dev` branch i.e. not even in current `master`. Recipe for success:

- build a firmware from the `dev` branch that includes the HTTP module (off by default): http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/build/
- flash the binary to your chip: http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/flash/
- use the HTTP module as documented: http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/modules/http/#httpget

If you decide to stick with the net module rather than using HTTP there's a small example in the docs: http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/modules/net/#netsocketsend

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I will give your suggestions a shot!